# Unexpected end of JSON input using cucumber-html-reporter

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using **Protractor** and *cucumber-html-reporter* to try generate a HTML report. So, in the *hooks* I have the following:

```
const {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
const path = require('path');
const reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');
defineSupportCode(function({After, Before}) {
    After(function () {
        var options = {
          theme: 'bootstrap',
          jsonFile: path.resolve( __dirname + '/../../report/cucumber.json'),
          output: path.resolve( __dirname + '/../../report/cucumber.html'),
          reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
          launchReport: true,
          metadata: {
              "App Version":"1.0.0",
              "Test Environment": "STAGING",
              "Browser": "Chrome  54.0.2840.98",
              "Platform": "Windows 10"
          }
    };
    reporter.generate(options);
  });
});
```

Also, in the *cucumberConfig.js* I have the following stretch:

```
cucumberOpts: {
    format: [ 'json:report/cucumber.json' ],
    require: [ __dirname + '/features/step_definitions/*.js' ]
},
```

After execution, I have the following result:

```
Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json:
'C:\dev\workspace\path\project\report\cucumber.json' SyntaxError:
C:\dev\workspace\path\project\report\cucumber.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.readFileSync
(C:\dev\workspace\path\project\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:69:17)

1 scenario (1 passed)
14 steps (14 passed)
0m23.233s
[10:02:00] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[10:02:00] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

PLEASE, What is the problem with this implementation? What am I doing wrong? Something missing?

Comment: Using SO Windows, why Protractor is creating path with "\\" in atribute _location_ to JSON output file?

Comment: The Protractor is generating a invalid output JSON format.

Comment: I found the problem. The protractor is writing an invalid path for attribute **location**. Please, Can any protractor maintainer help me?

Comment: Is it a Protractor issue or a protractor-cucumber-framework issue, because Protractor doesn't have any Cucumber logic. Secondly I would not advice the export to json method for output the log to a json method. Just create a listner for it in a hook. Then you have more control over the output. Made a boilerplate for myself with this hook in it, maybe it can help you, you can find it [here](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help @wswebcreation. The problem was solved, migrating _hooks_ code (cucumber-html-reporter) to **onPrepare** function.I just do not understand why this resolved.